# Magento 2 : Language translations add from admin side

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel, language-package

How to handle language translations from the admin side and reflect in frontend. I know how to handle from the frontend, inside `app/i18n/Magento/fr_FR.csv`, if we add in this file it will reflect on the frontend, shall we handle like this from the admin side, why because the client can handle from backend, instead of giving **translate content to us every time**.